# Default assignment operator checks for self assignment

Tags: c++, operators, standards

i would like to know if the default implementation of the assignment operator checks for self assignment, and so which of those two implementation can be considered the closest to the default one:

```
class A{
    int x;
public :
    ...
    // first one
    A& operator=(const A& a){
        if(this != &a) x = a.x;
        return *this;
    }
    // second one
    A& operator=(const A& a){
        x = a.x;
        return *this;
    }
}
```

I've searched for C++ standard but the only one that i can found is [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20161223125339/http://flash-gordon.me.uk/ansi.c.txt) but there is nothing about this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, implementations do not check for "self":

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_operator_(C%2B%2B)
>
> The **copy assignment operator**, often just called the *"assignment
>   operator"*, is a special case of assignment operator where the source
>   (right-hand side) and destination (left-hand side) are of the same
>   class type.
>
> It is one of the special member functions, which means
>   that a default version of it is generated automatically by the
>   compiler if the programmer does not declare one.
>
> The default version
>   performs a *memberwise copy*, where each member is copied by its own
>   copy assignment operator (which may also be programmer-declared or
>   compiler-generated).

Comment: That description does not preclude the possibility of the default generated implementation performing a check for self-assignment. The standard does not prevent it. The only way to know for sure is to actually look at the code the compiler generates.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The standard says, "The implicitly-defined copy/move assignment operator for a non-union class X performs memberwise copy-/move assignment of its subobjects."  How does that allow an implementation to check for self-assignment?

Comment: The Standard also "prevents" variable length arrays and flexible array members. Taking stuff out is bad form, but folks always seem to be adding stuff in.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm The standard merely says that the generated operator performs copy/move assignment of the individual members. It doesn't say the operator implementation can't also check for self-assignment first if it wants to.

Comment: @Remylebeau what is self assignment of a member has observable effect? Then it cannot be left out

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number the compiler has no way to know if such a side effect would exist for any given member. Such a side effect would require that member to have implemented an assignment operator for itself, and the compiler will not peek into that operator's implementation to see what it does.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes that was my line of thinking too, hence I'd expect that it is not permitted to optimize away self assignment, as it would (potentially) make an observable difference

Answer (score 3):

Assignment operator does not check against self assignment. Therefore your second implementation is the closest to the default one.

I can not see any word in standard about any such optimization and it would be strange if attributes of my class would not be assigned by compiler generated operator in some cases. Imagine that some attribute assignment is user defined one and does some uncommon task. Compiler does not know that and IMO should call them even if I assign an object to itself.